# How to extract text between two tags in an xml into a file

Tags: xml, batch-file

I have an xml with the following format:

```
<Record>
    <ID>aaa</ID>
    <NAME>aaa</NAME>
    <ADD>aaa</ADD>
</RECORD>
<Record>
    <ID>bbb</ID>
    <NAME>bbb</NAME>
    <ADD>bbb</ADD>
</RECORD>
```

I want to extract all text between the ID tags and put them in separate lines in another file.txt.

My .bat is as follows:

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion

for /F "delims=" %%a in (file.xml) do (
   set "line=%%a"
   for %%X in (^"^
% Do NOT remove this line %
^") do for /F "delims=" %%b in ("!line:>=%%~X!") do (
      if /I "!field!" equ "<ID_IC" for /F "delims=<" %%c in ("%%b") do >> file2.txt
      set "field=%%b"
   )
)
```

But somehow this is not working.  Can anyone pls help me with this?

Answer (score 0):

```
for /f "tokens=2,3,4delims=<>" %%a in (filename) do if /i "%%a%%c"=="ID/ID" echo %%b
```

should list your data as required.

Look at each line of data and tokenise using `<>` so

```
<ID>aaa</ID>
```

becomes token 1=leading spaces,2="ID",3=aaa and 4=/ID

Hence, if token 2 in `%%a` concatenated with token 4 in `%%c` is `ID/ID` then the required data is in `%%b` (token 3)

Simples.

Comment: I do not get your answer.

Comment: I do not understand what you mean.